# Hive connector in R / Rstudio

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, shiny, rstudio

Does anybody knows if it's possible to interface Hadoop with R / Rstudio ? If yes, HOW?

I have some hive's table and I'd like to accès them with R / Rstudio and within 'shiny' make a visual restitution (graphs etc...).

I would appreciate any help (ideas, code examples ...).

Comment: Look here[http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Hive+ODBC+Connector] and set-up ODBC connection with hive then you can simply call it as there a loads of documentation online on how to query tables within R

Answer (score 0):

Try the package [dplyr.hive.spark](http://github.com/piccolbo/dplyr.spark.hive). The docs are still a bit more geared towards spark, but I tested it against Hive with the latest HDP sandbox and things were going smoothly. If you give it a try please report any problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access hive tables on HDFS, you can use the RJDBC package and a JDBC connection (explained here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC). Then you can use RJDBC just like you would for a relational database except that it might launch some map/reduce jobs on your cluster to execute.